# pattern for email address with 2 letters between @ and

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following pattern `"^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"` for validating email address.

I want to add extra functionality here. i.e "Minimum 2 alphanumeric characters should be between @ and ."

Please suggest me solution.

Comment: `{2,}` instead of `+`.

Comment: [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Your Complex RegEx !!](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Comment: and will you accept internationalised domain names?

Comment: also, I know someone with an email `@e.gg`.  Your test would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very hard to do:

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]{2,}(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

The only thing I changed is the `+` for a `{2,}`. The `+` means 1 or more and `{2,}` means 2 or more.